# Interface and class in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, mvp

I have the following simple code of Presenter and View (MVP). I am not able to understand that, we just pass the view (i.e "this") in the view constructor to the presenter instance. But, in the presenter class, we have an interface as the parameter. I notice that, we implement the interface in the View. However, I don't understand how we are able to pass class (view instance using "this") when the parameter it accepts is an interface inside Presenter class constructor.

Please explain. I am kind of new.

```
interface IApplicationConnection
{
   string Connect { get; set;}
   void SetText(string text);
}

public partial class MyForm : Form, IApplicationConnection
{
  private Presenter _presenter;

  public MyForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _presenter = new Presenter(this);
  }

  public string Connect { get; set; }
}
```

### Presenter Class:

```
public class Presenter
{
  IApplicationConnection _view;
  public Presenter(IApplicationConnection view)
  {
     _view = view;
  }

  public void Clicked()
  {
    _view.SetText("Clicked");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile, the IApplicationConnection interface doesn't contain the SetText method you call from your presenter.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thank you, good catch, however, this is just for example and my concern is on Interface/Class thing.

Comment: I think then the mvp example is unfortunate because it distracts readers from your actual issue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Does it looks good now ? I edited. Please tell me if there are any other errors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you write, it seems that you are unsure on what "this" means. Actually, when in an instance (not static!) method, "this" always refers to the instance the method belongs to and is executed for.

In your example, "this" refers to MyView instance. Since the class implements your interface, you can pass it to the presenter constructor.

Suppose your class implements three interfaces:

```
public class A : I1, I2, I3 ...
```

and you are to pass it to

```
public void Foo( I1, I2, I3 )
```

then it would be legal to call Foo from within the class as

```
Foo( this, this, this )
```

Since the class implements multiple interfaces, it can "pose" as three different specifications expressed as interfaces.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. But can I pass like this: public void Foo(I3) alone ? using Foo(this) when Class is like Class A: I1, I2, I3

Comment: Yes, of course. Interface is like a "looking glass" you see your class through.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. However, I am doing rote learning now, I don't understand how it works though internally. :( I will see if there are any other google posts on this and also experiment well in my VS now. Thank you again.

Comment: Well explained @Wiktor +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is an instance of that class

MVP does some separation of concern and you can easily test the presenter with mocked views since you're injecting it through an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to pass the instance of class because the class must implement the interface which is being passed as argument in your presenter.

This is called the dependency injection via constructor. This way it makes the design decoupled because presenter doesn't have to worry or know about the implementation of interface IApplicationConnection_view. It just know that what ever is coming have the functionality implemented.

Also this way MVP pattern becomes more testable as you can mock the view with fake object and test your presenter in Unit tests. I hope this all make sense to you.

Comment: Hi Ven, thank you. However, I don't understand it being a beginner. I know interface is implemented by View. But don't always understand how we pass different object when the parameter is different. Well, for now, I am assuming what you say and here is my another question. If the View implements say 3 interfaces now. Then also I can just pass this view in the same way, with only one paramater "this" and in the Presenter Constructor, I can have any of the 3 views ? No objection ?

Comment: @Divine: from what you write it seems that you are unsure how "this" works and what it means.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: "this" means current instance and here in this context, it is MyView object ? Correct ? Is there any other meaning to it ?

Comment: Unless the all 3 views implement the interface specified in parameter shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @vendettamit: I am confused of what you have understood. My problem is, not 3 views, but only one view is there and 3 interfaces are implemented by this view. Say, like public partial class MyView: Form, IA,IB,IC

Comment: Well there's no limit of implementing interfaces on a class. It depends on Compilers capability on machine. so let's say you have IA, IB, IC implemented in MyView then the view can be passed to the presenters with consturctors presenter1(IA view), presenter2(IB view), presenter3(IC view). The one view will be accepted for all the presenters because it have implementation of all three types.

Comment: @vendettamit: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Vendettamit, sorry if my communication or representation was bad and misunderstood by you. I will do it all practically in my VS now and experiment it too slowly :) :) Cheers

Comment: Cheers!! No hard feeling buddy :P :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just how interfaces work. You can pass instance of a class to any method that accepts either

- this exact class
- any of its base classes
- any interfaces implemented by the class.

Comment: Thank you Alexei, but suppose if a class implements more than one interface and still can I pass only one parameter for any of the only one interface I wish ?

Comment: @Divine - not sure what is your question. If class implements interface instance can be passed to whatever accepts this interface. I.e from you other comment `Foo(I1 one, I2 two, I3 three)` can be called with passing the same instance of `A: I1, I2, I3` for all parameters: `var a = new A(); Foo(a,a,a);`

Comment: Thank you Alexei, I am afraid I am only understanding little. I will experiment it in VS practically. But, even then, I should take it as a concept, god knows internally what happens. I am more interested in how these conversions and executions take place inside CLR/.NET Framework or while compilation. Anyway!!! Cheers

Comment: Alexei, thank you so much, now I practised all the cases you bulleted. It works and I am happy too :) :) Thank you for the compendious points.... I will never forget this in life again. :)